# How should I save country in database with .NET backend

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, database-design

Using .NET in the backend I asked myself what is the best way to store the country name together with a customer service email address for that country in a sql table.

Should I use the TwoLetterISOLanguageName or LCID

What is more unique or better suited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. Both of those are Cultures rather than countries. If that's really what you want, store the `LCID`.

If you want to store the country, either store the name of the country (guaranteed to be unique) or the two letter country code of that country (not the language name).

Comment: The TwoLetterISOLanguageName like "ru" refers to russia for me. Thats enough for me, I do not need the 3letterisolanguagename which would give a finer detail of the country like siberia, ukraine whatever ;-)

Comment: @Elisa - Again, those refer to languages and cultures...not countries. You'll get `es` for any country that speaks Spanish (which includes quite a few countries).

Comment: I know justin its just our customer who provides the country information gives us "AR", "DE" etc...